# is there any difference between glycerin and glycerol?

Tags: nomenclature

In laboratory setting, is there a difference between glycerin and glycerol?

There are some conflicting info on this topic.

Comment: From what I have heard, glycerine is almost the same thing as glycerol.

Answer (score 10):

Nope, there is no chemical difference between glycerol, glycerin or glycerine.  All 3 names refer to the same compound, propane-1,2,3-triol.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

glycerols are the triol compound used for many purposes in pure or mixed form , but glycerine is the commercial name of glycerol, which is not pure ,which contain mostly 95% of glycerol , it can't be used when pure glycerol is required .

Answer (score 1):

Glycerin and glycerol are both names for the same molecule. However, depending on where you are getting the glycerol from, it could be more or less pure.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, glycerin and glycerol both refer to the same compound: propantriol.