# Differences in Glycerol Nomenclature

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Could someone differentiate between the terms glycerol, glycerin, glyceryl and glyceride?

Comment: Google is your friend! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycerol

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between glycerol and glycerin; they both refer to *propane-1,2,3-triol* (already answered [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/is-there-any-difference-between-glycerin-and-glycerol)).

[image]

Glyceryls refer to glycerol derivatives in which a hydrogen has been replaced (e.g. glyceryl trinitrate).

[image]

Glycerides represent a specific example of glyceryls and are fatty acid esters derived from glycerol (e.g. triacetin).

[image]